# How to make notification appear when someone comes online in Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, notifications, tweak, theos

I'm trying to make a tweak with theos to the Facebook app so that when a certain person comes online (defined by the user) a notification shows saying they came online.

Is there anyway of doing this for an iPhone/iPad/iPod and if so, how?

Thanks for reading